# What is the best css property to use for this situation

Tags: css, visibility

Imagine I have 3 lines of text for example like below:

Line 1: This is text 1

Line 2: This is text 2

Line 3: This is text 3

Now what I want to do is hide Line 2, but I want Line 3 to push up to the same position where Line 2 is, when Line 2 becomes visible then I want Line 2 to slot right back to where it was and Line 3 to go back to its original position.

So what I want to know is which is the best css property to use for this because I tried `visibility:hidden` and `display:none` and even though they both work when it comes to hiding Line 2 and making Line 2 reappear, they both don't allow Line 3 to move up automatically when Line 2 is invisible so it leaves a big gap in the middle which makes the appearance look a bit sloppy.

Thank You

Comment: Hmm...I'm guessing the elements are positioned absolutely, maybe trying `float:left`?

Comment: In what browser(s) are you seeing this behavior? Also, add to your post a simple example of your html and css.

Comment: The `display: none;` should work. Could You show some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: none;` on line 2 should move up line 3 and below automagically as it won't preserve space. You've got another problem with your positioning; absolute positioning stated by @JCOC611 is a good bet.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFsN6/2/ where span is hidden by each method and thus p container has no visible content anymore but exhibit 2 different behavio(u)rs. 0 height in case of `display: none;` and still the same look but empty in case of `visibility: hidden;`

Could you please post some code that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you answered your own question... `visibility:hidden` will preserve space in the layout for the element, while `display:none` will not, so seems to me like you want to use `display`, unless you also want to manipulate the height of the element itself to produce the effect.